# Split character vector into sentences

Tags: r, regex

I have the following character vector:

```
"This is a very long character vector. Why is it so long? I want to split this vector into senteces by using e.g. strssplit. Can someone help me? That would be nice?"
```

I want to split it into sentences by using the following pattern (i.e. period - space - upper case letter):

```
"This is a very long character vector."
"Why is it so long? I want to split this vector into senteces by using e.g. strssplit."
"Can someone help me?"
"That would be nice?"
```

Hence, period after abbrevations should not be a new sentence. I want to do this using regular expressions in R.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What about question mark? You split after it in two different ways?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution using strsplit:

```
string <- "This is a very long character vector. Why is it so long? I think lng. is short for long. I want to split this vector into senteces by using e.g. strssplit. Can someone help me? That would be nice?"
unlist(strsplit(string, "(?<=[[:punct:]])\\s(?=[A-Z])", perl=T))
```

Result:

```
[1] "This is a very long character vector."                             
[2] "Why is it so long?"                                                
[3] "I think lng. is short for long."                                   
[4] "I want to split this vector into senteces by using e.g. strssplit."
[5] "Can someone help me?"                                              
[6] "That would be nice?"
```

This matches any punctuation character followed by a whitespace and a uppercase letter. `(?<=[[:punct:]])` keeps the punctuation in the string before the matched delimiter and `(?=[A-Z])` adds the matched uppercase letter to the string after the matched delimiter.

**EDIT:**
I just saw you didn't split after a question mark in your desired output. If you only want to split after a "." you can use this:

```
unlist(strsplit(string, "(?<=\\.)\\s(?=[A-Z])", perl = T))
```

which gives

```
[1] "This is a very long character vector."                             
[2] "Why is it so long? I think lng. is short for long."                
[3] "I want to split this vector into senteces by using e.g. strssplit."
[4] "Can someone help me? That would be nice?"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the package `tokenizers` for that:

```
library(tokenizers)
tokenize_sentences(x)
```

where `x` is your character vector. It results in

```
[[1]]
[1] "This is a very long character vector."

[[2]]
[1] "Why is it so long?"                                                
[2] "I want to split this vector into senteces by using e.g. strssplit."

[[3]]
[1] "Can someone help me?"

[[4]]
[1] "That would be nice?"
```

You could then use `unlist` to remove the list structure.