# Add a list column to a dataframe

Tags: r, stringi

I have a dataframe with 100 rows
I have a column within the dataframe which consists of text.
I would like to separate the text column into sentences so that the text column becomes a list of sentences.
I am splitting with stringi package function `stri_split_lines`

**Example:**

```
rowID       text
1         There is something wrong. It is bad. We made it better
2          The sky is blue. The sea is green.
```

**Desired output**

```
rowID       text 
1           [1] There is something wrong
            [2]It is bad. 
            [3]We made it better
2           [1]The sky is blue.
            [2]The sea is green.
```

**I have tried**

```
dataframe<-do.call(rbind.data.frame, stri_split_lines(dataframe$text, omit_empty = TRUE))
```

Comment: please share data with `dput()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go, a solution from the tidyverse (and no longer using `stringi`):

Assume your dataframe is called `df`.

**Solution**

```
  library(dplyr)

  df %>%
    mutate(text= strsplit(text, "(?<=[[:punct:]])\\s(?=[A-Z])", perl=T))
```

Explanation: The `strsplit` in the mutate call returns a list, so you're data frame now has a true list-column. (The string-split regex was [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884556/split-character-vector-into-sentences))

**What if I want to split the list column into multiple rows?**

To split the members of that list into their own rows you have two options:

1. simply call `tidyr::unnest` on the list-column:

   ```
   df %>% tidyr::unnest(text)
   ```
2. Use  `tidyr::separate_rows` on the original dataframe (before creating the list-column):

   ```
   df %>% tidyr::separate_rows(text, sep= "(?<=[[:punct:]])\\s(?=[A-Z])")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
dataframe[["text"]] <- strsplit(dataframe[["text"]], split = "\\.")
str(dataframe)

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ rowID: int  1 2
 $ text :List of 2
  ..$ : chr  "There is something wrong" " It is bad" " We made it better"
  ..$ : chr  "The sky is blue" " The sea is green"
```

*Data*

```
dataframe <- data.frame(
  rowID = 1:2, 
  text = 
    c(
      "There is something wrong. It is bad. We made it better",
      "The sky is blue. The sea is green."
    ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Thanks @snoram. There are not always full stops at the end of lines which is why I wanted to use stri_split_lines. Im not sure why the output cant be sent straight to the dataframe though

Comment: `stri_split_lines(dataframe$text, omit_empty = TRUE)` does not split the strings... I think that might be the issue..

Comment: Im confused. It should split the strings and when I run it without trying to attribute it back to itself, it outputs the list with as above

Comment: It splits strings based on new line characters not "." so if you add new lines to the strings it will actually split them. Or you could use `stri_split_regex` if you can figure out the regex you would need

Comment: Agreed. `stri_split_lines()` splits based on the line the text is on, not based on sentences.