# Using Regex to find the characters '!' and '?' in a string

Tags: r, regex

I am doing a regex to only extract the first sentence of each paragraph. At the moment, I have a input vector like this:

```
text_insert <- c("hello, i am working through an r workbook. I am doing a regex expression.", "hi, how are you? I am great working through r")
```

My R code at the moment is:

```
gsub(pattern = "\\..*", replacement = ".", x = text_insert)
```

However this does not recognize `?` or `!` as the end of a sentence.

Any help of how to recognize `!` and `?` as the end of sentence as well?

Comment: Since your regex mentions neither `?` nor `!`, why do you expect it to find them? Your attempt is in some sense not a serious attempt at the problem.

Comment: How about `gsub(pattern = "([\\.\\?\\!]).*", replacement = "\\1", x = text_insert)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split character vector into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884556/split-character-vector-into-sentences)

Comment: In what context is a period _not_ the end of a sentence ?

Comment: @Frazer Bayliss, are you saying your first sentence is till `?` in your example that you posted up in the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can [use `|` to search for alternatives](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with a regular expression:

```
(\\.|!|?).*
```

Alternatively, you can [use a character class (`[…]`)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to look for “any one symbol inside the character class”:

```
[.!?].*
```

`.` does not need to be escaped when inside a character class.

---

Lastly, `gsub` is great for replacing text but what you’re actually doing is *searching* for text. There are better functions for that; it’s just that, in base R, they’re very inconvenient to use. However, we can use a package (e.g. stringr) to easily find matches.

Using this method means that you can describe much more directly what you’re searching for: a sequence of characters, finished by a punctuation mark:

```
〉stringr::str_match(text_insert, '.*?[.!?]')
     [,1]
[1,] "hello, i am working through an r workbook."
[2,] "hi, how are you?"
```

Note the `.*?`: [`*?` is the same as `*`, except *non-greedy* (aka. “lazy”)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy). This means that the match will stop as soon as the *first* instance of any of `.!?` is found.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP, The first sentence ends at `?`. A bit odd, but this is his requirement from the question

```
/^([^?!]*)/
```

captures the first sentence right upto `?`

Explanation:

```
/^    -- beginning of the string, to capture the first sentence.
[^?!]*  -- move till you find either ? or !. Note that ^ in character class represents negation , meaning [NOT ? or !]
```

here is the demonstration on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tShOnd/1)