# Split string in R based on punctuation

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Does anyone know how to split a string in R based on punctuation or how can I remove everything before punctuation, but not the punctuation?

```
x <- c("a>1", "b2<0", "yy01>10")
```

The following is the desired result:

```
"a", "b2", "yy01"

">1", "<0", ">10"
```

To get the first part I can do:

```
gsub("\\b\\d+\\b|[[:punct:]]", "", x)

"a"    "b2"   "yy01"
```

But I am not sure how to get the second one. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46884556/5325862) post might help you figure out lookahead / lookbehind patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `strsplit` from `base R` with regex specified to split at the word boundary preceding the operators `<>`

```
do.call(cbind, strsplit(x, "\\b(?=[<>])", perl = TRUE))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]  
#[1,] "a"  "b2" "yy01"
#[2,] ">1" "<0" ">10"
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.